# Can I escape curly bracket symbol in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm using the terraform `template_file` data resource to create a file that should be written to the dynamically-created EC2 instance when I apply the stack. In other words, I want this file to be created in the home folder of the newly-created EC2 instance. However, this file contains curly bracket syntax `${}`, which terraform is trying to interpolate. How can I escape these curly brackets?

As background, I'm using the `cloud-config` syntax to write these files.

Ex:

`${username}` should be written to the file, *not* interpolated in terraform.

Even when I use the double dollar sign `$$`, terraform still fails because it can't find the variable:

`... failed to render : <template_file>:105,18-26: Unknown variable; There is no variable named "username".`

Comment: Can you include a few lines of your template file script in the question? Thanks

Comment: Use $username without the braces

Answer (score 5):

Terraform uses a fairly unique escape for curly braces:

| Sequence | Replacement |
| --- | --- |
| $${ | Literal ${, without beginning an interpolation sequence. |
| %%{ | Literal %{, without beginning a template directive sequence. |

Documentation for reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html

Comment: it's fairly common to use double dollar sign to escape dollar sign variables. OP even mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

FYI I ended up working around this by writing the template in another file, then reading it into the terraform stack using the `file` method:

```
data "template_file" "config" {
  template = "${file("./user_data.tpl")}"
}
```

Comment: This seems not to work with

`NAME_TEMPLATE: %{{service_name}}.%{{environment_name}}`

Answer (score 0):

For example if you would like to add into Tags {{_payload.ref}}  as it was in my case, I have done it this way:

```
tags                    = ["CRITICAL", "\u007B\u007B_payload.ref\u007D\u007D"]
```

so

```
\uNNNN  Unicode character from the basic multilingual plane (NNNN is four hex digits)
```

ref.page: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings